# Camera Calibration with Freenect Kinect driver

Tags: ros, calibration, kinect, freenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm working with a Kinect and the Freenect driver package.

The Kinect is working fine and the distances provided are also fine. But I think I should calibrate the Kinect, if I do not people might call me stupid or something. I can calibrate the Kinect using opencv_cam_calibration package. This package gives a camera_conf.xml file that is the configuration of the camera. I can convert the file from .xml to .yaml.

My question is where do I put this file in the Freenect Kinect driver? I can't seem to find the place where to put it.

Anyone knows? Thanks so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216558/camera-calibration-with-freenect-kinect-driver/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out.

You need to put the .yaml confg file in: home/user_name/.ros/camera_info/camera_config.yaml file.

---

Originally posted by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) with karma: 162 on 2015-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-08-27**:
Shouldn't that file be automatically written? http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration

**Comment by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on 2015-08-27**:
I used that package, I did it this morning. Yes it creates the file, but then you have to put it that place so the freenect package can detect the file. I had to rename the file also.